# Passing more than one JSON object to the Post method

Tags: typescript, asp.net-web-api

In `TypeScript` I have something like this:

```
$.post(this.serviceUrl + '/GetMyCodes', JSON.stringify(item.MyCodeList.trim()), function (CodeData: Something.SomethingElse) {
```

and my POST method is something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMyCodes([JsonBody] string myCode)
```

My problem is how can I need to pass one more value to this service. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a model which holds all values you want to post

```
public class postModel
{
    public string myCode { get; set; }
    public string myDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Define the controller to read the model from the body

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetMyCodes([FromBody] postModel model)
```

Then create an object in your client that matches the model structure

```
var obj = { myCode: 'myCode', myDescription: 'myDescription' };
$.post(this.serviceUrl + '/GetMyCodes', JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: What is [FromBody] ?

Comment: @Bohn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: ok I don't have it. I was wrong, the HTTPPost is inside a normal MVC Controller class.  No Web-API

Comment: @Bohn ok, np. U can remove the FromBody attribute. It should work without it. By default all parameters in post are read from the body